# Are there any case studies which provess that Re-design of existing Website helped to get more traffic and business significantly ?

Tags: website-design, design, web, conversion

Are there any case studies which provess that Re-design of existing Website helped to get more traffic and business significantly? If craiglist redesign their website today can it get more traffic is business?

Do people re-design their websites which are already doing well, because they think the current design is outdated or they expect more profit/traffic/business/ in that?

Comment: Yes there are case studies (a simple google search will find many) and for both reasons (and more besides), but this question seems rather broad and also more about marketing than user experience specifically? Also 'redesign' is a vague term. It could mean starting from scratch or modifying a shopping cart, or adding new functionality. Is there a particular UX topic you're trying to explore here?

Answer (score 4):

I'm going to interpret your question as "UX: can anyone show me whether it works?"

The best example would be the [$300,000,000 button](http://www.uie.com/articles/three_hund_million_button/). In short, an ecommerce website was designed to ask users' to register before purchasing. By changing this to allow customers to purchase *without* registering, the company earned $300,000,000 more that year.

And $15m of that was within the first month - so it's easy to make the attribution to the UX change.